# MIPS sw dependency

Tags: dependencies, mips

I have question about MIPS code and dependency.
 If i have following MIPS code.

How it works without any forwarding unit?

How many stalls needed to be insert?

```
7   ADD $t5, $t4, $t5
8   SUB $t5, $t5, $t3 
9   SW  $t5, 24($t0)
```

In my opinion:

line 7-8 WAW, RAW dependency t5  2 cycle stall

line 8-9 RAW dependency t5,  1 cycle stall

Am i right? or did i miss something?

Is there any dependency between line 7 and line 9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close

```
ADD $t5, $t4, $t5
```

executes in ALU, and needs to write-back `$t5` for the next line. That means a stall for MEM and WB, therefore 2 cycles.

```
SUB $t5, $t5, $t3
```

executes in ALU too, that's why it's stalled for 2 cycles.

```
SW  $t5, 24($t0)
```

Now here comes the problem. I believe that registers are read on ID, which means that the stall here would be 2 cycles again, to wait for WB of `$t5`. It may not seem so, but until WB of `SUB`, `SW` may have to wait on ID. 
[image: MIPS pipeline]

**EDIT:**
I wrote down the pipeline to make it easier to see.

```
+----+-----+-------+-------+
|    | ADD |  SUB  |  SW   |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
|  1 | IF  | -     | -     |
|  2 | ID  | IF    | -     |
|  3 | EX  | ID    | IF    |
|  4 | MEM | stall | stall |
|  5 | WB  | stall | stall |
|  6 | -   | EX    | ID    |
|  7 | -   | MEM   | stall |
|  8 | -   | WB    | stall |
|  9 | -   | -     | EX    |
| 10 | -   | -     | MEM   |
| 11 | -   | -     | WB    |
| 12 | -   | -     | -     |
+----+-----+-------+-------+
```

Comment: thanks for replying, if add 5 nops
7   ADD $t5, $t4, $t5
    2nops
8   SUB $t5, $t5, $t3 
   3nops
9   SW  $t5, 24($t0)
then it works fine?

Comment: Eh, I'd also put 2 nops before line 9, for the reason in the last paragraph.

Comment: im sorry, just confused . the result of SUB write back at WB stage. if i put 2 nops before line 9,  ID stage of line 9 will be at same cycle with WB of SUB   .

Comment: @eclipse0922, I did a bit of a research and found out that for example MIPS 4K uses only a 1 cycle stall for memory operations. I'd rather check if this isn't your case, as you could be right from the beginning.